# Interface with objects, but with specific values

Tags: typescript

I wanted to create an interface with pages, and languages they use.

```
export interface Pages {
    Name: string,
    Langs: AllLangs
}
```

Langs have 3 properties: name (for example `Vue`), color (never mind, I just want to display them with color), and type for example `LangType.FRONTEND` (I keep all of them in array):

```
enum LangType {
    FRONTEND,
    BACKEND,
    DATABASE
}

interface SingleLang {
    Name:string,
    Color:string
    Type: LangType
}
```

And now I want to define `AllLangs` interface like that

```
interface AllLangs {
    Frontend: {
        Lang: SingleLang, // only with Type: Langtype.FRONTEND
        Percentage: number
    }[],
    Backend: {
        Lang: SingleLang, // only with Type: Langtype.BACKEND
        Percentage: number
    }[] | null,
    Database: SingleLang | null // only with Type: Langtype.DATABASE
}
```

Of course, I can define langs like that:

```
interface AllLangs {
    Frontend: {
        Lang: {
            Name: string,
            Color: string, 
            Type: LangType.FRONTEND
        }
        Percentage: number
    }[],
    Backend: {
        Lang: {
            Name: string,
            Color: string, 
            Type: LangType.BACKEND
        }
        Percentage: number
    }[],
    Database: {
        Name: string,
        Color: string, 
        Type: LangType.DATABASE
    }
}
```

But I don't think it's a good idea. I'm just learning TypeScript and my English is bad, but I hope you understand. Have a nice day!

Any leads, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html)

```js
enum LangType {
    FRONTEND = 'Frontend',
    BACKEND = 'Backend',
    DATABASE = 'Database'
}

type Language<Type extends LangType> = {
    Name: string,
    Color: string,
    Type: Type
}

type AllLangs = {
    [Prop in LangType]: Language<Prop>
}

export interface Pages {
    Name: string,
    Langs: AllLangs
}

type Test = AllLangs[LangType.BACKEND]['Type'] // LangType.BACKEND
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAMghiA5gFQJ4AdhQN4CgoFQBiASgPIByyAohQCJQC8UA5EQE4D2IALqACYsANPkIAhAIIBhANK0GzFmLgBjANYDhognQnIJkgMrUmrOnB5wARnADOwFrgC%20uXDwxZ4SMHETAAPGiYUMAAHnwg-LawCCgeAHymeIRQFHAQwABcULY87ACWSCIpUpwANpzs2bkFRdpQQVkNHs6u7sESZWVeiNHMyYQA2gAKXOhQhTFIjQC62T0%20fv6jnOjxrbhh6JU8E7zA7ABmqljDvsDRAwRpGdV5hYjFhD222Z3dsbYb7VjIF7vMd4vQY9RoAOkksnkM0GLEaLBmUAA9EipnFMBDpHJ6LggA)